# Can't remove underline from a span inside a p

Tags: html, css

Basically I have a `span` which is inside a `p`, on CSSI have the p underline, but I can't seem to remove the underline from the `span`, you'll find some code example below:

```css
p{text-decoration:underline;} span{text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<p>Hello World <span> I'm spanning... </span> </p>
```

All the text is underlined. Could you please give me a hand?

Comment: <p> This is just <span>a sample text</span> that will demostrate my issue </p>

Comment: remove the text decoration on <p>

Comment: `p span {text-decoration:none;display:inline-block}` you need to reset the block formating context of the span

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block;` on `<span>`. Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
p {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

span {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

body {margin: 20px;}
```

```html
<p> This is just <span> a sample text </span> that will demostrate my issue </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at this backwards. Since the `p` element has an underline, the entire thing will. What you need to do is inverse your markup to give the `span` an underline where you want it. Something like this:

```css
span {
 text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<p>
 <span>This is just </span>a sample text<span> that will demonstrate my issue</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way around, wrap the text content you want underlined in spans and style these:

```
<p> <span>This is just</span> a sample text <span>that will demostrate my issue</span> </p>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/BQyJU0dPzmZaAVEMrKkL?p=preview